# why image is not showing in imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to set image for imageview using URL

I tried below code...

```
NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/Files/Clients/thumb/2e10ec86-f323-4889-a996-00cf6758f354.JPG"];
NSLog(@"imageURL===%@", imgURL);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
NSLog(@"=====%@", data);
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

This is working perfectly.

Now I tried URL with the data from the feed and tried below.

```
NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
NSLog(@"imageURL===%@", imgURL);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
NSLog(@"=====%@", data);
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

This gives me output as below.

```
2013-08-15 11:22:56.725 Sahhtna[7555:11303] imgURL==http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/Files/Clients/thumb/2e10ec86-f323-4889-a996-00cf6758f354.JPG
2013-08-15 11:22:56.726 Sahhtna[7555:11303] =====(null)
```

I don't understand why I get data as (null), when the strings are same? As data is null, I am not getting any image in my UIImageView.

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

When I do `NSLog(@"[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]==%@", [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]);` I get output as `[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]==(null)`

---

I got the reason. At the end of string, there is Enter (new line). How can  I remove it?

I got the solution.

There were enter and white spaces.

```
NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
imgURL = [imgURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
imgURL = [imgURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Сan you NSlog for[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] ?

Comment: @Leta0n : its giving null

Comment: Try directly comparing the imgURL strings to see if there might be a difference.

Comment: Hm... Try [NSURL URLWithString:[imgURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]

Comment: @ThomasW : As I stated in first part with string (actual link) its working... only when I fetch from feeds, it gives me problem

Comment: @Leta0n : still data is null...

Comment: The `NSStrings` are what is different about the two code snippets, so that is the most likely cause of the problem. Chances are that while the strings look they same, the really are different.

Comment: @Leta0n : when I do the NSLog with UTF8, I get output as `[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]==http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/Files/Clients/thumb/2e10ec86-f323-4889-a996-00cf6758f354.JPG%0A%20%20%20%20`

Comment: So You need [NSURL URLWithString:[imgURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] - Replacing :) Try it...

Comment: @ThomasW : when I do the NSLog with UTF8, I get output as `[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]==http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/Files/Clients/thumb/2e10ec86-f323-4889-a996-00cf6758f354.JPG%0A%20%20%20%20`

Comment: @Leta0n : still data is null...

Comment: What is the value of `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sahhtna.hardtask.org/Files/Clients/thumb/2e10ec86-f323-4889-a996-00cf6758f354.JPG"] isEqualToString:imgURL]`?

Comment: Looks like you should trim the string before you convert it to an NSURL. Look for `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` in the NSString docs. Use that with `[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterset]`

Comment: @ThomasW : its false... but why is this false?

Comment: @ThomasW : At the end of string there is enter... how can I remove it?

Comment: It looks like @BobVork has the answer.

Comment: Look like you are trying to download images in loop `(cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method. Use `SDWebImages` library for that. It needs lazy loading. Remember loop doesn't wait for download.

Comment: @TheTiger : for SDWebImages, first I have to get image.. As now I am getting images, I am implementing the same... :)

Comment: No dude ... There is a category of `UIImageView` just set image with url and place holder image to imageView. And one reason why your `NSURL` is **null** is you know already :) URL doesn't supports spaces and many other characters.

Comment: You can check them at [HTML Characters Code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) need to replace the normal characters with their corresponding html characters. For Example replace space by %20.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar i have posted exact answer please check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were enter and white spaces. Below did trick.

```
NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
imgURL = [imgURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
imgURL = [imgURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
  [self downloadingServerImageFromUrl:myImageView AndUrl:imgURL];
}

-(void)downloadingServerImageFromUrl:(UIImageView*)imgView AndUrl:(NSString*)strUrl
{

NSString* theFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[[strUrl lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tmp/%@",theFileName]];


imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIActivityIndicatorView *actView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[imgView addSubview:actView];
[actView startAnimating];
CGSize boundsSize = imgView.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = actView.frame;
// center horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

// center vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

actView.frame = frameToCenter;


dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSData *dataFromFile = nil;
    NSData *dataFromUrl = nil;

    dataFromFile = [fileManager contentsAtPath:fileName];
    if(dataFromFile==nil){
        NSString *url =[strUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        url=[url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
        url=[url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError* error = nil;
        dataFromUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
        }
    }

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if(dataFromFile!=nil){

            myImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:dataFromFile];
        }else if(dataFromUrl!=nil){
            myImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:dataFromUrl];
            NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tmp/%@",theFileName]];

            BOOL filecreationSuccess = [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:dataFromUrl attributes:nil];
            if(filecreationSuccess == NO){
                NSLog(@"Failed to create the html file");
            }

        }else{
            myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.jpg"];
        }
        [actView removeFromSuperview];
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""

replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""
```